# wordpress site migration to xampp; Need redirect to access site images (easy?)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, xampp, migration

Wordpress site run locally with XAMPP and accessed via localhost/mysite (stored at C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite) isn't picking up images stored at C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\wp-content\uploads\

Most of the img url's from live site I hardcoded the full path, and still show up as,

```
https://live_site.url/wp-content/uploads/.../imgx.jpg
```

(Can't access Wordpress dashboard currently so can't edit pages directly.)

The img urls that weren't full path show up as,

```
localhost/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/imgz.jpg
```

(which should presumably be, localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/.../imgz.jpg)

Added redirect to .htaccess (which I tried putting first in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\ and then C:\xampp\htdocs) --

```
Redirect 301 https://live_site.url/wp-content/uploads/  localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads
```

Doesn't work, causes ERROR 403 ACCESS DENIED! for the full page, which won't go away until I actually delete .htaccess itself.

(And the above redirect in any case would not solve the problem with the img url's that weren't full path.)

In the MySQL DB for mysite, I have set both wp_options.site_url and wp_options.home to localhost/mysite (no db access issues)

Comment: "`https://live_site.url/...`" - You've hardcoded the URL with a HTTP**S** protocol? That means you'll have to install a security cert locally (or at least a self-signed cert that you "accept").

Comment: thx sir, will google that (still the prob w  the img urls which aren't full path)